# How to Convert Column data into row data with comma separated value using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table Like as Follows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrFUq.jpg)

I want Out put like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21Ccy.jpg)

how to Achieve this using SQL in Oracle database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `listagg()`.  The only caveat is that you need to specify the ordering for the values:

```
select stdname, listagg(marks, ', ') within group (order by ?) as marks
from t
group by stdname;
```

If you want them in order of the marks:

```
select stdname, listagg(marks, ', ') within group (order by marks desc) as marks
from t
group by stdname;
```